# FragmentPagerAdapter passing list of object to fragment when data is ready

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I created application using **FragmentPagerAdapter** with 3 fragments inner static class inside let say MainActivity. Basically android studio template of tabbed activity generate the code that way, also in android documentation use that inner static class too just for example
[creating swipe view](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral)

But it will be bad for performance because I have to make all variables and functions become static to make it work, also its not the right thing to do.

So I try to split the Fragment to its own class, and from this article 
[communicate between fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)
it tell us how to sending variable/action callback from fragment to parent activity (in my case is MainActivity)

And after some research, sending data from activity to fragment can be done using interface too. But it becomes both are implementing each other and I get

> cyclic inheritance error

Most of the topic on the internet discussing how to pass data from activity to fragment are happened when creating the fragment, using bundle and etc.

For dynamic application that request data to server that approach seems like cannot be used.

**Is there any correct way how to pass data (in my case is List Object) from activity to fragment at certain time when the request to server is finished (the fragment already created before)?** Thank you.

Here is some of my code

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    //On create
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);


    //adapter
    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Home", "History", "My Account"}; 

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return BlankFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return FragmentHistory.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return FragmentAccount.newInstance();
            default:
                return BlankFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

}
 @Override
public void onFragmentInteraction() {
    getKegiatan();
}
}
```

BlankFragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


private final Context context = getContext();
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private int mRole;


private ImageView ivNoData;
private ExpandableListView elvKegiatan;
private ListView lvKegiatan;

private EditText etFrom, etTo;
private String dateFrom, dateTo;

private List<Kegiatan> listKegiatan;
private List<Kegiatan> superKegiatanSaya;
private List<Kegiatan> superKegiatanAnak;



public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static BlankFragment newInstance() { //String param1, String param2
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                getResources().getString(R.string.myspkey), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        mRole = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.splogin_role), 0);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kegiatan, container, false);


    FloatingActionButton fabAddKeg = view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddKegiatan);
    fabAddKeg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(context, TambahKegiatanActivity.class));
        }
    });


    lvKegiatan = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewKegiatan);
    elvKegiatan = view.findViewById(R.id.elvKegiatan);

    View buttonSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonPressed();
        }
    });


    etFrom = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextFrom);
    etTo = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);

    populateList();
    prepareDate();


    LinearLayout llRangeKeg = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRangeKeg);
    switch (mRole){
        case UserConst.ROLE_USER:
            break;
        case UserConst.ROLE_SUPER:
        case UserConst.ROLE_CEO:
        case UserConst.ROLE_CFO:
            llRangeKeg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case UserConst.ROLE_ADMIN:
        case UserConst.ROLE_FINANCE:
            llRangeKeg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fabAddKeg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
    }

    return view;

}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 )Define a listener interface. I usually do this as an inner interface within the activity:

```
 public interface DataUpdateListener {
        void onDataUpdate(List<Object> mData);
    }
```

2 )make object of interface

```
DataUpdateListener dataListener;
```

3 )Add the register  methods to the activity:

```
public void registerDataUpdateListener(DataUpdateListener listener) {
     dataListener=listener;
}
```

4 )Have your fragments implement DataUpdateListener:

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements DataUpdateListener {
```

5 )implement the method

```
 @Override
    public void onDataUpdate(List<Object> mData) {
        // put your UI update logic here
    }
```

6 )Override onAttach() and onDestroy() in the fragments to register/unregister:

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        ((MainActivity) activity).registerDataUpdateListener(this);
    }
```

7 ) When you update UI in Fragment

```
dataListener.onDataUpdate(mData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use EventBus for this situation

1. Create a class for the event (for exemple Data)

   public class Data {
       public List objects;
       //getter & setter
   }
2. In your Fragment put a subscriber. Add :

   @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
   public void onMessageEvent(Data data) {
       //you can get List of objects by data.getObjects();
   };
3. Register and unregister your subscriber (in the Fragment)

   @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

   @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
4. In your Activity post the event when data is ready

   Data data = new Data();
   data.setObject(objects);
   EventBus.getDefault().post(data);
5. Do not forget to add on grade dependencies :

   implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

More information [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)